# Select multiple rows based on List of arguments in single Transaction

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I want to fetch multiple values from the table based on list of arguments in single query (**Single transaction**). **Please note I'm asking how to make this in JOOQ.** To make it clear, I have something like this:

**Code**

```
List<Integer> id = new ArrayList<>();
id.add(1);
id.add(3);
```

**Table in DB**

```
ID | Title |
------------
 1 |  one  |
 2 |  two  |
 3 | three |
 4 | four  |
```

Now based on list of id's I want to fetch only first and third row in single transaction. Is it somehow possible ?

I've already tried something like this, but none of methods accept list or any collection as argument.

```
dsl.select(Tables.TABLE.TITLE)
   .from(Tables.TABLE)
   .where(Tables.TABLE.ID.eq()) // no list argument
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to use a [comparison predicate](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/conditional-expressions/comparison-predicate/) but an [in predicate](http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/conditional-expressions/in-predicate/) using [`Field.in(Collection)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Field.html#in-java.util.Collection-):

```
dsl.select(Tables.TABLE.TITLE)
   .from(Tables.TABLE)
   .where(Tables.TABLE.ID.in(id))
```

Or directly, using [`Field.in(T...)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Field.html#in-org.jooq.Field...-):

```
dsl.select(Tables.TABLE.TITLE)
   .from(Tables.TABLE)
   .where(Tables.TABLE.ID.in(1, 3))
```

In other words, this isn't really a question about jOOQ (or using jOOQ with transactions), but it is a question about SQL in general.